# Go build still linked to old version of a library even after library upgrade

Tags: go

go build failed with a old version of a library. Have removed the old version, installed latest verion of the library and retried go build. But go build still linked to old version of the library, What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove go build cache with `go clean -cache`. This should solve the issue.

If you have multiple version the same library, specific version shall be linked as,

```
CGO_LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/Cellar/x264/r3095/lib" go build
```